# Unable to persist new object graph using JPA (hibernate) with simple oneToMany - ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I am attempting to persist/merge a brand new object graph through jpa but it seems like the order of persistance is incorrect as it tries to save sub objects who have a constraint on their parent being present.

```
public class ObjectA implements Serializable {
  ...
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "objectAId")
  private List<ObjectB> objectBList;
  ...
}
```

and

```
public class ObjectB implements Serializable {
  ...
  @JoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_A_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private ObjectA objectAId;
  ...
}
```

I will create a new entity ObjectA and along with several new ObjectB entities and add them to Object A.  When i merge ObjectA I get the following:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: com.mycompany.data.ObjectB.objectAId
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: FYI - There's a good blog post about bidirectional relationships [here...](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/16/jpa-implementation-patterns-bidirectional-assocations/)
That blog has lots of good JPA related posts...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's your responsibility to keep both sides of bidirectional relationship in consistent state for objects in memory. In other words, when you add `ObjectB` to `ObjectA.objectBList`, you also should make `ObjectB.objectAId` pointing to the corresponding `ObjectA`.

Moreover, without `optional = false` you would be able to persist objects without errors, but the relationship between them wouldn't be persisted if `ObjectB.objectAId` is `null`. It happens because Hibernate looks at the state of the owning side of relationship when saving it to the database, and in the case of bidirectional one-to-many relationship owning side is the "many" side (`ObjectB`)

Comment: +1. Also note that the owner side of the relationship is the one **without** the mappedBy attribute. So, what will be taken into account by Hibernate is the relationship from B to A, not from A to B

Comment: You are correct sir.  I failed to properly interpret the exception.  I set `ObjectB.objectAId` with `ObjectA` and it persists as expected.  Thanks!